How to make a transparent overlay control overlapping another control in C# WinForms .NET 8?
I'm trying to make a transparent overlay that will stack on top of another control. It should have an opacity and text in the middle. I'm in the middle of a .NET Framework to .NET 8 upgrade and all the overlays stopped working.
This is the .NET Framework code that worked before. It works by painting the control Magenta and then we use the Magenta color as the key when we want to remove the color.
class OverlayControl : Control
{
    public OverlayControl()
    {
        this.SetStyle(ControlStyles.OptimizedDoubleBuffer, true);
        this.SetStyle(ControlStyles.AllPaintingInWmPaint, true);
        this.SetStyle(ControlStyles.UserPaint, true);
    }

    protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnPaint(e);

        e.Graphics.FillRectangle(Brushes.Magenta, this.DisplayRectangle); // NET8 no longer works
    }

    protected override void OnHandleCreated(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnHandleCreated(e);

        // NET8 no longer works
        NativeMethods.SetWindowLongPtr(this.Handle, NativeMethods.GWL_EXSTYLE, new IntPtr(NativeMethods.WS_EX_LAYERED));
        NativeMethods.SetLayeredWindowAttributes(this.Handle, (uint)Color.Magenta.ToArgb(), 0, NativeMethods.LWA_COLORKEY);
    }
}


If you want your Control to have an opacity, you have to change LWA_COLORKEY to LWA_ALPHA. The former sets the transparency color key, so that the specified color is not rendered on that surface. Then of course set a bAlpha value > 0, otherwise you don't see anything -- In the Designer, you cannot just use OnHandleCreated() to set styles and attributes. You have AllPaintingInWmPaint and UserPaint. You need to also call that code in OnPaint() <- just once; use a flag to signal that the attribute is set and test DesignMode to determine whether to do this or bail

BTW, as it is, it shouldn't work that well (or at all, in the Form Designer) no matter what version of .NET you're targeting. Also, when calling SetWindowLongPtr(), also call GetWindowLongPtr() first to get the styles currently set, then add yours

@Jimi thank you for your response! I'm not looking to get this working in the DesignMode since my project is code only. Do your comments still apply?

In relation to LWA_COLORKEY and LWA_ALPHA and the opacity level, yes. If you don't use a Designer and you don't plan on building something that others can use in a Designer, then that code can be called just from OnHandleCreated(), when the Form is first shown. But I'd suggest using a method that calls the API functions, plus a public Property that allows to set the bAlpha value, so you can change the opacity at run-time., if you need to.  If so, then you can call this method and change the opacity setting when needed

I found the answer to my question. There was never anything wrong with my code. In the process of upgrading to NET8, the app.manifest file had been deleted.
I then stumbled upon this in the win32 documentation:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winmsg/using-windows#using-layered-windows
Basically, adding the guid for windows 10 compatibility fixed my issue right away.
